# Div Background Not Showing Up

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I'm working on variied.com. Currently the logo is displayed through a set of H1 tags as the background. I want to change it to a DIV for SEO purposes, but anytime I change #logo to a DIV, nothing appears.

Comment: Are you giving some size (width and height values) from css to the div? An empty div has dimensions 0x0 even if background is set. So, it doesn't show up.
Edit: Your website is currently using h1 tag for logo, while your css probably has div for it, because changing h1 to div by inspector brings up the logo

Comment: That's not the way you should ask questions on SO. Post the minimal code that reproduces your issue. Might be helpful for future visitors too.

Answer (score 2):

Check your CSS around your #logo.  You may need to change "h1 #logo" to "div #logo"

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet has the styles for `#logo` actually applied to `h1#logo` and `h1#logo a` on **lines 262** and **268**, respectively. Prefixing your classes and ID's with a selector is generally not advised because of the exact problem you are running into – if you change the markup, the CSS breaks. Simply remove `h1` from those rules and everything will work as expected.